# tcolorbox poster - draw on the background behind the foreground

Tags: tcolorbox, posters

Below is a small tcolorbox poster example. Does anyone know how to draw on top of the background image, but behind the posterboxes.

As a subquestion, the tcolorbox manual, page 150, about *interior style image* mentions that one can combine *fill stretch image* and *interior style* to blend picture and background. Hoever it is not clear to me how one would add suitable paths for this.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[
    coverage = {
      spread,
      interior style = {
        fill stretch image=example-image-c.pdf,% from mwe bundle
      },
      top=2em,
      bottom=2em,
      left=2em,
      right=2em,
    },
    poster = {
      % showframe, 
      columns=3,
      rows=3,
      spacing=2em,
    },
    boxes = {},
    fontsize = 16pt,        
]

\posterbox{name=title,column=1,below=top,span=3}{
  Test
}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question here is a method to draw on top of the background, behind the foreground. Just remember to place relative to the `interior` node, everything outside this node is clipped away.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[
    coverage = {
      spread,
      interior style = {
        fill stretch image=example-image-c.pdf,% from mwe bundle
      },
      overlay={% here
          \fill[red] (interior.north) circle (3cm);
      }, 
      top=2em,
      bottom=2em,
      left=2em,
      right=2em,
    },
    poster = {
      % showframe, 
      columns=3,
      rows=3,
      spacing=2em,
    },
    boxes = {},
    fontsize = 16pt,        
]

\posterbox{name=title,column=1,below=top,span=3}{
  Test
}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```